# Need help getting input from user on type of book in loops then using it in equations

Tags: java, loops

So I'm having a hard time figuring out how to take the user input on what type of book isbeing donated and using that information to calucalate the donation credits. Same goes with the purchasing scenario. I have a small bit of the prompt I was tasked to do as well as my code that I have so far. I'm not looking for an answer, but some guidance. I feel like I have all the info to do it but Its just getting it in order. Thanks for reading. and I HAVE TO USE LOOPS, part of the assignment.

Prompt: Write a program that allows one customer to complete a visit to the used bookstore.  The program must allow the customer name to be input at the keyboard.  Each customer will input the number of books being donated and the number of books being bought.  For each book being donated, the user will enter the book type of book either hardback or paperback.  The same information needs to be entered by the user about each book that is purchased.  The program must print out a receipt for the customer showing the total credit earned by donations, the total cost of the purchased books, and the amount of money owed by the customer to the used bookstore for the visit.  The receipt for the customer should be printed out in the following format:

Code:

```
package bookStoreRecieptpackage;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BookStoreRecieptClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declare variables
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // open input stream
        String cleanUpStr;              // clean up keyboard buffer
        int numBooksDonated;            // number of books donated by customer
        int numBooksPurchased;          // number of books purchased by customer
        double totalCredits;            // total credits earned by customer
        double purchaseTotal;           // total purchase of books by customer
        double visitTotal;              // total visit cost for customer
        String bookType;                // Type of book customer donating/purchasing
        String customerName;            // Name of customer
        //int ctr;                      // counter
        double costHardbacks;           // cost of hardbacks in order
        double costPaperbacks;          //  cost of paperbacks in order
            
        // declare constants
        final double HARDBACKDONATION = 0.75;   // donation credit for one hardback book
        final double PAPERBACKDONATION = 0.25;  // donation credit for one paperback book
        final double COSTHARDBACK = 1.0;        // cost of one hardback book
        final double COSTPAPERBACK = 0.50;      // cost of one paperback book           
        final String HARDBACK = "H";            // Hardback book
        final String PAPERBACK = "P";           // Paperback book
                                            
            
        // initialize variables             
        cleanUpStr = "none yet";
        numBooksDonated = 0;            
        numBooksPurchased = 0;      
        totalCredits = 0.0; 
        purchaseTotal = 0.0;
        visitTotal = 0.0;       
        bookType = "none yet";  
        customerName = "none yet";
            
        // print out your name
        System.out.println("Input until 100 for Tolantio Ganzi");
            
        //Prompt user to enter customer’s name.
        System.out.println("Please enter customers name: ");
        customerName = input.nextLine();
        //Prompt user to enter total number of books being donated
        do {
            //prompt user to enter number of books being donated
            System.out.println("Enter number of books being donated: ");
            numBooksDonated = input.nextInt();
            cleanUpStr = input.nextLine( );
                
            if(numBooksDonated < 0) {
                System.out.println(numBooksDonated + " is not a valid number. ");                       
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("What type of book are you donating? Enter H or P.");
                bookType = input.nextLine();                        
            }
        } while(numBooksDonated < 0);

        //Prompt user to enter in the type of book [hard, paper]
        //Validate total number of books being donated [loop, if, else]
        //Prompt user to enter total number of books being purchased
        //Prompt user to enter in the type of book [hard, paper]
        //Validate total number of books being purchased [loop, if, else]

        //Calculate 
        visitTotal = (purchaseTotal - totalCredits);
            
        //Print output
        System.out.println("Customers name\t\t" + customerName);
        System.out.println("Number books donated\t " + numBooksDonated);
        System.out.printf("Donate Credit\t\t$%.2f ", totalCredits);
        System.out.println("Number Books purchase\t\t " + numBooksPurchased);
        System.out.printf("Purchase Total\t\t$%.2f ", purchaseTotal);
        System.out.printf("Total Owed for Visit\t\t$%.2f ", visitTotal);

        // close input stream
        input.close( );
    } //end main

} //end class
```

Comment: Make use of Book and Customer classes

Answer (score 0):

You already have a do-while loop around the code prompting the user to enter their book transactions. Perhaps after entering the information once, the user needs to be asked whether they have more donations or purchases to make? See my example below about how you might do that. You can use a do-while loop to do this, but I find a while loop easier to read. I removed all the comments and variables which were not pertinent to the demo.

```
public class BookStoreRecieptClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
    String customerName = input.nextLine();

    int totalBooksDonated = 0;
    boolean customerIsNotDone = true;
    while (customerIsNotDone) {
      System.out.println("Enter number of books being donated: ");
      final String booksDonated = input.nextLine();
      try {
        final int booksDonatedInt = Integer.parseInt(booksDonated);
        if (booksDonatedInt > 0) {
          totalBooksDonated += booksDonatedInt;
        } else {
          throw new NumberFormatException();
        }
      } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        System.out.println(booksDonated + " is not a valid number of books. ");
        continue;
      }

      // Ask the customer if she wishes to continue
      System.out.println("Type any key to continue, or type 'quit' to finish.");
      final String next = input.nextLine();
      if (next.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
        // exit the loop
        customerIsNotDone = false;
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Customers name\t\t" + customerName);
    System.out.println("Number books donated\t " + totalBooksDonated);

    input.close();
  }
}
```